# Dynamic routing not rendering the react component when used with express

Tags: express, react-router

I have the following routes in the main.jsx (entry point),

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route,IndexRoute, browserHistory  } from 'react-router';
function render(){
    ReactDOM.render((
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/viewq/:id" component={v}/>
            <Route path="/postq/:id" component={p}/>
        </Router>
    ), document.getElementById("app"));
}

render();
```

when i access the following url e.g. host/viewq/id=14, the component is not getting rendered.

Have the following the the server.js file, to return the index.html that has the bundled file (main.js),

```
app.get('*', function (request, response){
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'))
})
```

How to make this work ?